# Close all forms besides 'switch board'

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I need to be able to close a form and have it close all other forms besides the switch board.  I tried using this code but it also closes the frmSwitch even though I attempted to code it to close all but that.  Where did I go wrong?  I am supposed to use the actual name of the form correct?

```
Form[] forms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToArray();
foreach (Form thisForm in forms)
    {
        if (thisForm.Name != "frmSwitch") thisForm.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you got the name right? Step through the loop with the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: Are you closing `frmSwitch`'s parent form?

Comment: frmSwitch is the parent form.  Every other form is a child form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `thisForm is frmSwitch`, and then close the rest.

```
foreach (Form thisForm in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (!(thisForm is frmSwitch))
        thisForm.Close();
}
```

You also don't have to use `Cast<Form>` and `ToArray`, you can enumerate `FormCollection`

Comment: Okay thanks! That is good to know but I am still having the same problem.  ALL the forms including frmSwitch is closing!

Comment: @korrowan, if all the other forms are inheriting from `frmSwitch` ? or all the other forms are MDIChildren of `frmSwitch` ?

Comment: I am not sure what MDIChildren mean.  What I did is use owner so I could pass PKs like so frmSwitch _owner;
        public frmSummary(frmSwitch owner)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _owner = owner;
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.frmSummary_FormClosing);
        }

Comment: When you close a form the number of forms in the collection changes and you'll have an exception, if you make an array, it stays the same... (with null refs though).

Answer (score 0):

This will work assuming you are closing from your "main form"

```
var list = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToArray();
foreach (Form item in list)
{
    if (item.Equals(this)) continue;
    item.Close();
}
```